# Do iOS devices have a pop-up Japanese-English Dictionary like on the Macintosh?

Tags: iphone, ipad, dictionary

On the Mac if you three-finger tap a word, a dictionary definition appears. I'd like to know if I would be able to get this on an iPad specifically for the Japanese dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on iPad on iOS5.1.1. At the moment, I am having trouble getting the same functionality on iPhone on iOS6.0.1, though. Japanese dictionary is there, but I can't get the English-Japanese one. Your mileage may vary, of course.

---

**EDIT** May 27 2013: To restore Japanese<->English dictionary, you will need to [jailbreak the device and delete the Japanese<->Japanese dictionary](http://atylmo.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/howto-restore-the-japanese-english-dictionary-in-ios-6/). These dictionaries conflict, and the Japanese<->Japanese dictionary wins almost every time.

I have also asked [if it is possible to *only temporarily* jailbreak an iOS 6.1.2 iPhone 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92470/temporary-jailbreak-of-iphone-4-for-purposes-of-deleting-a-dictionary) for purposes of removing the mentioned dictionary. As of the time of this edit, this has not been answered; I am nonetheless linking to that question in case someone answers it by the time someone reads this.

Comment: As far as I can determine, the translation dictionary for Japanese was dropped in iOS 6, or is no longer accessible. There have been various complaints in the ASC.

Comment: @TomGewecke Someone posted on ASC that Apple Support told them it's a bug. Hopefully that's it -- it's just a bug.

Comment: Yes, hopefully that means they will fix it.  But Apple Support is often clueless when it comes of language issues...

Comment: The translation dictionary has been restored in iOS 7, but many users complain that it has to be repeatedly downloaded and will not stay permanently active on the device.