# Temporary jailbreak of iPhone 4 for purposes of deleting a dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, dictionary

I need to temporarily jailbreak my iPhone 4 to [fix Apple's iOS 6 bug making it impossible to access Japanese-to-English dictionary](http://atylmo.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/howto-restore-the-japanese-english-dictionary-in-ios-6/).

All I need and want to do is delete Japanese-to-Japanese dictionary.

Is it possible to tethered jailbreak iPhone 4 temporarily, delete the relevant folder, and merrily continue using the device in a non-jailbroken fashion?

Comment: Also, I suppose a related question could be: does iTunes backup/restore the whole `/User/Library/` folder. If so, then you could backup/restore after you jailbreak and be fine.

Comment: @grgarside No reason for _tethered_ jailbreak per se. I am currently uninterested in jailbreaking the current phone. It does everything I need, except for the dictionary. I'm happy with jailbreaking the tablet, but have no need to do so on the phone.

Comment: Why is it so important together rid of that dictionary?

Comment: @TomGewecke If you google around, the Japanese-to-Japanese dictionary blocks Japanese-to-English dictionary from ever appearing. On iOS 6 only. The only documented solution on iOS 6 is to get rid of the Japanese-to-Japanese dictionary. For a beginner studying a language, a monolingual dictionary is useless; on iOS 5, the bilingual dictionary was practical, detailed and very easy to use.

Comment: Aha, I had forgotten that. In case it doesn't work out, some app options are at http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2013/02/japanese-english-dictionary-missing-in.html

Answer (score 1):

**Unjailbreaking a device without restoring it is currently impossible.**

If you don't mind using a jailbroken device until it's fixed, you could jailbreak normally, then when Apple releases the fix, just backup with iTunes, restore to the latest iOS, and then restore the backup.

Comment: One of the large issues I have with this is the inability to go to-and-from jailbreak as I please. If I jailbroke now, use it jailbroken, then want to undo it -- I can't, because I'll be forcibly restored to 6.1.3, and unable to jailbreak again. I do have 6.1.2 SHSH, but nonetheless. Plus, keeping the phone jailbroken and then simply loading it with a bunch of cr*p like I did on the iPad and previous phones is too tempting. ;-)